# Can I show mix success/error notifications of docker in hosting Kubuntu 20?

Tags: docker, laravel-mix

In my docker/laravel project (with hosting Kubuntu 20) I added support of  mix success/error notifications

```
  FROM php:8.0.9-apache
    RUN apt-get update && \
    ...
    libnotify-bin \
```

But anyway these notifications are not visaible in my OS.

If there is a way to show notifications from my docker app my hosting Kubuntu 20 ?

Thanks in advance!